# why wil R NOT detects the duplicate character？

Tags: r, duplicates

I'm trying to delete duplicate id data in my data frame

```
buying<-buy_nobuy[duplicated(buy_nobuy[,1])==F,]
```

after this, it tells me that there is no duplicated data left

```
length(buying[duplicated(buying[,1])==TRUE,1])

[1] 0
```

but when I check manually in the global environment, I found that 
actually, there are still duplicate data exist (like the pic show)

[image]

And I check if I test the rows, which has the same id, what will happen：

```
> buying[9,1]==buying[71,1]
[1] FALSE
```

**Seems ridiculous. I guess this may be some data type problem？

anyone knows how to solve this？**

by the way, I read the data frame in the type of character since ID can not be read as numeric or it will be presented in an exponential way and lose real ID

```
buy_nobuy <- read.csv('community_achievement_buying.csv',colClasses= c(Id="character"))
```

I FOUND that there is extra space here in row71 as you said.

```
> print(buying[9,1])
[1] 76561198321932950\t
73039 Levels: 76561197960272112\t ...
> print(buying[71,1])
[1] 76561198321932950\t\t
73039 Levels: 76561197960272112\t
```

Comment: Try: `buy_nobuy<-buy_nobuy[!duplicated(buy_nobuy[,1]),]`

Comment: If a simple modification like the above doesn't work, you will need to provide the actual data (maybe just those two rows) so that we can test & verify ourselves. Just images of data isn't going to be useful at all.

Comment: Often these issues are due to leading or trailing whitespace

Comment: Voting to close as no reproducible example. To request reversal of closure post output of `dput(  buying[c(9,71),1])` as [edit].

Comment: Keep consistent data frame names. You deduplicate a data frame called `buy_nobuy` and find duplicates in another data frame named `buying`. Maybe they are completely different data frames? Maybe you create a duplicate when you create `buying`?

Comment: @joran well, StackOverflow seems do not provide the attachment function.

Comment: @42- I do not quite understand the meaning of voting the close.
well, the data have 100,000 rows and read from csv, so sorry for no reproducible example. 
But thanks for your comment, so I can realize that I could print the two rows out and found that there is extra /t at row71, as DSGym and James they have suggested. I re-edit the post, thanks.

Comment: Actually that is NOT an extra space, but rather an "extra" tab-character. ONe of those items has a a single tab and the other has 2 tabs. So I suppose you have now offered sufficient information to do a full diagnosis of the underlying pathology despite your apparent inability to follow explicit directions. And it shows that the guess offered in the accepted answer was not quite correct.

Comment: With good reason! We don’t want or need huge data sets, but creating a small, reproducible example is a crucial first step to both debugging a problem yourself and for asking for help online. But it does require some effort and research on your part. Googling “r reproducible example” will likely take you to a SO question with LOTS of advice on how to do this.

Comment: @42- thank you. I think in the literature meaning space and tab is quite the same meaning since they can all be seen as a split symbol, and it did point out there may be something other than what we can "see" in the RStudio window, so  I accepted it as a suitable answer. Sorry for not knowing too much exact terminology

Comment: @joran thank you, I'll try it next time. since this problem seems to be solved after I print the two rows out.
I'm pretty new to R, codes or terminology, thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data <- data.frame(
  id = c("123456789", "123456789 "),
  buy = c(1,1)
)
```

Like already mentioned, characters vectors often have trailing white space => You will not see this in the R Studio Data viewer. There is an easy way to detect if these values are really the same: Try `charToRaw` to see if both IDs are the same.

```
apply(data[1], 1, charToRaw)
[[1]]
[1] 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39

[[2]]
 [1] 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 20



data$id <- trimws(data$id) # Thanks @ Mako212

apply(data[1], 1, charToRaw)

      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   31   31
 [2,]   32   32
 [3,]   33   33
 [4,]   34   34
 [5,]   35   35
 [6,]   36   36
 [7,]   37   37
 [8,]   38   38
 [9,]   39   39
```

Comment: Base R has `trimws()`, not sure there's any need for `stringr` here

Comment: did not know that function to be honest, thank you :-)